# how to get two totals depending on conditions in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the total of users who have seen 7 videos and the total of users who have not seen 7 videos

my table DB
[image: table]

porcentaje_avance = 1; means the user has fully watched the entire video.
porcentaje_avance < 1 "example 0.123, 0.150"; means the user has not fully watched the entire video

i try this code, but show diferente data

```
$data = LeccionesCapacitacion::select(DB::RAW('COUNT(CASE WHEN lecciones_users.porcentaje_avance = 0 THEN 0 END) AS total_not_see_all_video')
    ,DB::RAW('COUNT(CASE WHEN lecciones_users.porcentaje_avance = 1 THEN 1 END) AS total_see_all_video'))
    ->join('lecciones_users','lecciones_users.leccion_capacitacion_id','=','lecciones_capacitacion.id')
    ->join('users','users.uuid','=','lecciones_users.uuid')
    ->where('users.region_id',1)
    ->get();
```

the result of my code

[image: the result of my code]

Comment: If the DB table in above image is `lecciones_users` and you have defined One-to-Many relationship between `User` and `LeccionesUser` then you can get the desired result with 2 queries on User model.

Comment: Why are you didn't convert it to 2 separate queries?